# Retrieval of txt file gives an error when deployed in IIS 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a text file **RHKLIS.txt** which is placed in **D:\ drive**. I have found out some piece of code to retrieve the
path of the text file and it is **working fine while running in the local host**. I have deployed the code in some test machine using **IIS 7.0**
and tried accessing the same code but its not retrieving its giving the error as **Sql transaction has closed in the line  if (!File.Exists(path)).**
So i got to know that path specified is an issue in the code.But still i am not aware of what type of error it is because there is a same text file placed in the D:\ drive in the same test machine.

in web.config

```
<appSettings>

  <add key="LISpath" value="D:\RHKLIS.txt"/>

</appSettings>
```

.cs file

```
   string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LISpath"].ToString(); 
   FileStream fs = null;
   if (!File.Exists(path))
   {
       fs = File.Create(path);
       fs.Close();
   }

   StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path);

   sw.WriteLine("O~" + billHospNo.Text.Trim() + "~ ~" + opBillNo.Text + "~" + billDate.Text + "~" + itemCode.Text + "~" + itemName.Text + "~" + p.Honourfic + "~" + p.Patient_Name + "~" + p.Gender + "~" + p.Age + "~" + "Y" + "~" + "~" + "~" + "~" + "~" + "~" + department.SelectedItem.ToString() + "~" + billDate.Text + "~" + itemDept.Value + "~" + deptName + "~" + yearOB + "~" + due);
   sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is making the assumption you have you have full admin rights on the server.

Right-click on the folder, select properties. A property window of the folder will open - select the Security tag. You will see two lists - the top is for the users or groups and the bottom is the rights - click the Edit button under users.

Another widow will open - click the Add button - which will open another window. Make sure the locations is for the local machine and not a domain, then click advanced, and click the Find Now button. Look through the list until you see the IIS_IUSRS user and double-click on it. This will put the user in the bottom text filed of the selection window. Just click ok and it will automatically give that user the required permissions for the folder - then just click on ok all the way until all the windows are closed.

I hope this helps... This allow read-only access to that folder from IIS.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a security problem. Firstly, the file being on the root of D: would mean that you would have open the whole D: to the IIS server (not good practice). Rather create a new folder, add the IIS_IUSRS user (with read & execute, List folder contents and Read permissions) - then put the file in that folder. Change the setting in the config file and that should work...

Comment: Is it necessary to add IIS_IUSRS? Is there any other methods like modification of code to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi Shreyas - yes, it is inherit in the server architecture. An IIS server will not see any folder unless this user has been added in the permission. So no, one cannot change this in the code.

Comment: Come to think of it, what are the requirements? Can you not supply this information via a webservice?

Comment: Can u mention how to add the IIS_IUSRS?